# Can't install Provisioning Profiles on iPhone (iOS 8 beta 4 / Xcode 6 Beta 4)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6, osx-yosemite-beta

I can't install any of my iOS developer distribution or developer linked provisioning profiles onto my iPhone 5S running iOS beta 4 with Xcode beta 4 on OS X Yosemite dev preview 4. I have reinstalled iOS 8 with a restore, same for yosemite and Xcode betas, revoked and created new dev certificates, deleted and added new certificates to my Keychain access, and made sure all my new provisioning profiles are for the correct certificates. Yes I am a developer and have my iPhone udid added to by developer portal account. I have also made sure to include this iPhone in the provisioning profiles and doubled checked to make sure I'm logging into my dev account on Xcode. I just can't seem to get the profiles to install :(

I have included some screenshots of Xcode supposedly telling me the profiles are installed, but my phone says otherwise. I have also tried emailing them to myself and installing that way but my phone still says no profiles installed.

I would really appreciate i if someone could help me.

Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot 2] [image]

Answer (score 8):

Xcode is correct - the profiles are on your device and you can confirm this by installing and trying to run an app that relies on one of those profiles.  The reason you're not seeing the provisioning profiles on the Profiles page is that iOS 8 no longer exposes provisioning profiles through the user interface.

Comment: Any idea about why _iOS 8 no longer exposes provisioning profiles through the user interface_?

Comment: Apple views the exposure of the provisioning profile to users not using the dev tools as an unnecessary exposure. iOS should take care of provisioning automatically for the everyday user - removing them when expired, untrusting developers when their last app is uninstalled, etc. Any flow that requires a normal user to deal with provisioning profiles is now viewed as flawed.  Provisioning profiles can still be managed by dev tools like Xcode or by device management systems like MDM. This philosophy is mentioned in WWDC 2014's talk on Managing Apple Devices around ~42 minutes in.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem last night and this morning. I am using xcode 6 beta 4, ipad mini ios 8 beta 4, iphone 5 ios 8 beta 4.

Go to developer.apple.com go to your certificates, revoke your current development certificate. create a new one and download it. shut down xcode. and drag and drop your newly downloaded certificate into xcode on your dock. let xcode open.

to make sure your certificates are properly loaded, go to xcode/preferencecs/accounts/view details to see if the certificates & provisioning profiles are there.

if all looks good so far, then clean your project, build it and then run it on your iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is old question, but I encountered exactly same problem, tons of Provision profiles from old experimentation and was searching hours how to remove them and I found a solution which I share for any developers that need it in future.
Solution is suitable for iOS 9 and XCode 7 (I believe for iOS 8 also).

1. Using App Store install **Apple Configurator 2** on your Mac.
2. Run it and connect mobile phone.
3. Double click iPhone or iPad or any other device and switch left menu to `Profiles` to check is there any really present.
4. If Yes, the go back and Right click the device, choose menu `Remove->Profiles`.
5. Now *very carefully* check and select which profiles you do not need and click `Remove Profiles`

[image]

I can confirm, that there is nothing to see from user interface of the device, only special tools can show real view.

I hope this will save hours to others.